# Using ng-bind-html or something similar in Select-Option tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngsanitize

I have this code below. Which is a straight forward way of using NgOptions to plot some options in a form.

```js
function NameCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.theOptions = [{
    'label': 'The Opt<sup>&trade;</sup>',
    'id': 3
  }]

}
```

```html
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular.js Example</title>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="x.id as x.label for x in theOptions">
        <option value="">Select</option>
      </select>
</body>

</html>
```

My question is: Is there any way I can make the Option `The Opt<sup>&trade;</sup>` to render **The Opt<sup>™</sup>** in a Select Dropdown? As I cannot use ng-bind-html. Is there any way I can achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `ng-options`, here are a few related [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505150/how-do-i-use-ngoptions-with-a-string-that-contains-html-entities) and here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VyffiSZWn2potp5sQNcf?p=preview) showing this solution with your code.  Hope this helps. Note that I also changed your tags to an html entity code.

Comment: Selecting this as a "Correct" answer because in this method I don't need to change my HTML and probably JS too. Rather it will be much easier just to change my resource bundle. Plus using `ng-repeat` to obtain Select-option Dropdown is frowned upon.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ng-repeat` and use `ng-bind-html` with that. See the code below:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="x in theOptions" ng-bind-html="x.label" value="{{x.id}}" id="{{x.id}}"></option>
</select>
```